# addDivisionEquality with Java google or-tools CP-SAT

Tags: optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I need to add the following constraint using [google CP-SAT solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver):

(x+y+z)/(x+y+z+k) < 10

The [addDivisionEquality](https://google.github.io/or-tools/java/classcom_1_1google_1_1ortools_1_1sat_1_1CpModel.html#a5fbb526d9d241b398980965a6ad29cf8) method signature is:

```
Constraint addDivisionEquality (IntVar target, IntVar num, IntVar denom)
```

Where

```
IntVar target = model.newIntVar(0, 10, "(x+y+z)/(x+y+z+k)");
```

But now I need to define the numerator and denominator as `IntVar` types while they are the sum of multiple intVars.

The Java package provides a class called [SumOfVariables](https://google.github.io/or-tools/java/classcom_1_1google_1_1ortools_1_1sat_1_1SumOfVariables.html) to sum intVars but the `addDivisionEquality` method requires `IntVar`. I would expect it to get [LinearExpr](https://google.github.io/or-tools/java/interfacecom_1_1google_1_1ortools_1_1sat_1_1LinearExpr.html) instead.

How can I define the numerator and denominator as `IntVar` types?

Comment: Hey, can you share how you run the given java program?

Comment: I've followed https://github.com/magneticflux-/ortools-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IntVar numerator = model.newIntVar(0, 10, "(x+y+z)");
model.addEquality(target, LinearExpr.sum(new IntVar[] {x, y, z}));
```

This being said

```
model.addLessThan(LinearExpr.sum(new IntVar[] {x, y, z}), 
                  LinearExpr.scalProd(new IntVar[] {x, y, z, k}, new int[] {10, 10, 10, 10}));
```

is much simpler.

And finally, if all variables are positive,

```
(x + y + z) / (x + y + z + k) is always <= 1
```